# Solving for Cheryl's bday using vba with for statement

Tags: excel, vba

So I am a beginner in vba and I have been practicing on solving a logic problem using vba. So far I have entered the data in my worksheet and I am trying to create a run button that will show the result of Cheryl's bday. How would I be able to compare value in a cell to the values in a range to get an output of unique values? I know that I have to get the unique dates first. (This is not a hw problem or for credit, this was given from professor to practice for a quiz)

the question is :
Albert and Bernard just become friends with Cheryl, and they want to know when her birthday is. Cheryl gives them a list of 10 possible dates:
May 15 May 16 May 19
June 17 June 18
July 14 July 16
August 14 August 15 August 17
Cheryl then separately tells Albert which month her birthday is in, and tells Bernard which day of the month her birthday is.
Albert: I don't know when Cheryl's birthday is, but I know that Bernard does not know too.
Bernard: At first I didn't know when Cheryl's birthday is, but I know now.
Albert: Then I also know when Cheryl's birthday is.
So, when is Cheryl's birthday?

This is the code I have so far and I am planning to first find unique date then I want to clear contents of the columns that those unique dates are found

```
Sub LoopCells1()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    For c = 1 To 12
        If Cells(c).Value <> Range("A2:D4").Value Then
            MsgBox c & " is a unique date"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: No this is not homework it was given for no credit and only to be used for practice, @braX

Comment: @KenWhite thank you I didn't know I was looking on this website if there was something similar,  this is what I have done so far ***Sub LoopCells1()
Dim c As Long
Dim counter As Integer
For c = 1 To 12
    If Cells(c).Value <> Range("A2:D4").Value Then
    MsgBox c & " is a unique date"
    
    End If
    Next c
    
    End Sub***

Comment: You have few choices: 1) loop through the range and compare each individual cell 2) use `Find` or 3) `Match`. But at a glance of the question, you should know there's no unique date...

Comment: @RaymondWu Well those are applications already on excel, I am trying to create a for loop statement that will check if a value in cell c has a duplicate. I believe the unique dates are 18 and 19 right? all other numbers have duplicates.

Comment: @RaymondWu so do you know what I am doing wrong in my code that it isn't working? I believe I defined the range that I have the date on my worksheet and there are 12 cells in the range, I  was trying to make it return a Msgbox that showed the two dates that don't have duplicates

Comment: 18 and 19 are unique day, not date. you did not show what's in the Range so we won't know what are you comparing and `not working` is pretty much a useless info to us since there's no details. Perhaps try fully qualify your Range so that it does not refers to the wrong worksheet. e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range` and lastly, debug by stepping through your code to see if it's doing what you are expecting it to be @Kevin

Comment: I was not able to upload a pic of my worksheet but I have a table with 5 columns

Comment: @RaymondWu starting from A1 to E1 I have May, June, July, august. Under the columns I have the dates given for those months, for may (15,16,19) June(17,18), July(14,16), August (14,15,17) and my last column the header is "duplicates" and cells "E2" and "E3" are going to be my output cells for the two unique days

Comment: @RaymondWun I am getting an error on ** If Cells(c).Value <> Range("A2:D4").Value Then, is it better to put if cells("A2").value <> Range ("A2:D4").value then ?

Comment: Do a `Foreach Rng in Range("A2:D4").Cells` loop and compare against `Rng.Value` within the loop. there's plenty of examples on how to loop through cells the moment you google it. Post a new question when you are stuck with your question being specified to the problem, not your quiz.